# R auto.arima package version 3.22 Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used)

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using auto.arima() like that:

```
F12.Xreg <- fourier(NEW.JMB,12)
F4.Xreg<- fourier(NEW.JMB,4)
fb<-cbind(F12.Xreg, F4.Xreg)
fit <-auto.arima(NEW.JMB, D=0, max.P=0, max.Q=0, xreg=fb)
```

I don't know how can I avoid error:

```
Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used) : 
 system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.64873e-30
Error in if (diffs == 1 & constant) { : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In auto.arima(NEW.JMB, D = 0, max.P = 0, max.Q = 0, xreg = fb) :
  Unable to calculate AIC offset
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two fourier matrices have identical columns so the design matrix is not full rank. You can create the fourier terms with a single call to `fourier()`.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have the same problem with two fourier matrices fourier(x, 7) and fourier(x,365).  When I cbind them together like above, I can see the singular values are all nonzero, so xreg is still full rank.  Any idea why the error still comes up?

Comment: Ah sorry, it was actually because of another external variable I had included in xreg.  Strange though that the singular values are still nonzero